# Can a JWT produced with RS256 be decoded by the jwt.io website?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jwt

recently I made my first Express server and added user authentication using jwt. Now I'm looking for a way to encrypt that jwt so that users will not be able to see the payload in the https://jwt.io website.

Does anyone know if this encryption algorithm will prevent the users from seeing the payload without the public / private key?

Comment: If it is *properly __encrypted__* and your users don't have the key, then nothing can decrypt it, by definition.

Comment: I was under the impression that the key was there to prevent everyone to temper with the token content, but in any way to avoid decrypting token ?

Comment: @nubinub JWTs are *signed* by default, which makes them plainly readable, but temper-proof. There's also a spec for *encrypted* JWTs, which makes the content unreadable as well.

Comment: @deceze Which is that spec to make the JWT's unreadable?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Encryption

Answer (score 4):

`RS256` uses digital signature to ensure Integrity, Authenticity, and Non-repudiation on the produced token. It does not ensure Confidentiality.

If you want to use JWE (JSON Web Encryption) with JWT you can. And since you are both the issuer and recipient of the token I would suggest to use symmetric encryption. Actually you may not use asymmetric crypto because anyone with the possession of the public key would be able to encrypt and you cannot ensure you are actually the one who originally produced the JWE.

You need an implementation/library that supports JWE formatted JWTs. That would give you Integrity, Authenticity, and Confidentiality. e.g.:

```
npm install jose@4
```

To encrypt use [EncryptJWT](https://github.com/panva/jose/blob/v4.x/docs/classes/jwt_encrypt.EncryptJWT.md#readme)

```js
import * as crypto from 'crypto'
import { EncryptJWT } from 'jose'

const secretKey = crypto.randomBytes(32) // you would pass your own 32 byte secret as a Buffer

const jwt = await new EncryptJWT({ 'urn:example:claim': true })
  .setProtectedHeader({ alg: 'dir', enc: 'A256GCM' })
  .setIssuedAt()
  .setIssuer('urn:example:issuer')
  .setAudience('urn:example:audience')
  .setExpirationTime('2h')
  .encrypt(secretKey)
```

This produces a JWE-formatted JWT like so that, without the knowledge of `secretKey`, cannot have its *payload* decrypted.

```
eyJhbGciOiJkaXIiLCJlbmMiOiJBMjU2R0NNIn0..Wz7DdwAPlbq4cYxn.OMfWJTMuyfLcdN4g541KfcDFKaL5y2bBaFIxuC_-mVa7YLE4M7bVfiO9R2umvpD_acGj5l3gvxulcRnHzBMeRpm4qgbJuWVdA1fYUOguDs1h2xtesZ_9iZUEtcu3hEJ1wVM46ad-9dPebe_VaWwe4XVU5GM.7lDflVFg_Qm3N88xX8Dy1A
```

To decrypt and validate the JWT Claim Set use [jwtDecrypt](https://github.com/panva/jose/blob/v3.15.4/docs/functions/jwt_decrypt.jwtDecrypt.md#readme)

```js
import { jwtDecrypt } from 'jose'

const { payload, protectedHeader } = await jwtDecrypt(jwt, secretKey, {
  issuer: 'urn:example:issuer',
  audience: 'urn:example:audience'
})
```

Comment: How can I create that 32byte buffer key? @FilipSkokan

Comment: You can generate one with e.g. `openssl rand -hex 32` and then `Buffer.from(hexSecret, 'hex')`. Keep it a secret tho, do not commit it to source control, when deploying use environment variables or secret managers to source the value.